# How to Import Java classes and Alloy-UI tag library in Dynamic Datalist (DDL) Freemarker/Velocity Display Template (Liferay 6.2)

Tags: liferay-6, velocity, freemarker, alloy-ui

Is there any way to Import Java classes and Alloy-UI tag library into a Liferay 6.2 Dynamic Data List (DDL) Freemarker/Velocity Display Template?

For example, when editing the Display Template of a Dynamic Data List portlet (DDL), is there any way to import a class such as **WorkflowConstants.java** and use it?

Also is there any way to use add dependencies for alloy-ui tags with Display templates?

Thank you!

Comment: you mean you want to call Java class method and its fields in freeMarker template

Comment: Correct. I want to call Java class methods and fields in the freemarker or velocity template of a Dynamic Data List. It specifically needs to be from within the confines of the DDL portlet. Also I would like to access alloy-ui tags.

Comment: It's easy to call Java method and fields from ftl template but I don't know exact about alloy-ui tags . If you are making html markup or using it in jsp then its okay, Just you need to add alloy-ui tags in tempalte

Answer (score 1):

You can [access static fields,static methods](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html) and non-static methods from freemarker template. Here is sample Program.

Custom constant class but you have WorkflowConstants in life ray you can access same

```
public class WorkflowConstants {
    public static int ACTION_SAVE_DRAFT = 1;
    public static String CONTEXT_COMPANY_ID = "MTRX_78";
    // static method
    public static String test() {
        return "executed Constant#test()";
    }
}
```

**//FooCallMethod class**

```
public class FooCallMethod {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.setClassForTemplateLoading(FooCallMethod.class, "");
    config.setObjectWrapper(new DefaultObjectWrapper());
    config.setObjectWrapper(ObjectWrapper.BEANS_WRAPPER);

    Map<String, Object> dataModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    TemplateHashModel staticModels = BeansWrapper.getDefaultInstance().getStaticModels();
    dataModel.put("statics", staticModels);

    TemplateHashModel fileStatics = (TemplateHashModel) staticModels
            .get("java.io.File");

    Cal cal = new Cal();
    dataModel.put("cal", cal);
    dataModel.put("File", fileStatics);

    Template template = config.getTemplate("/foo.ftl");

    StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
    template.process(dataModel, out);
    System.out.println(out.getBuffer().toString());

}

}
```

**Cal.java**

public class Cal {

```
public int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

public int mul(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

}

**Template**

```
${statics["com.tset.WorkflowConstants"].test()}

${statics["com.tset.WorkflowConstants"].ACTION_SAVE_DRAFT}
${statics["com.tset.WorkflowConstants"].CONTEXT_COMPANY_ID}

2+3   =  ${cal.add(2,3)}
10/2  = ${cal.mul(10,2)}

${statics["java.lang.System"].currentTimeMillis()}
```

**Note:**

You can easily use `Dynamic Data Lists` in freeMarker tempalte
[see here](http://www.liferay.com/web/marcellus.tavares/blog/-/blogs/12150383) it is mentioned in velocity but need to use freeMarker syntax.

Use freemaker language: more powerfull and full support of taglib, velocity, it's too poor to use taglib

https://www.liferay.com/it/web/mika.koivisto/blog/-/blogs/using-freemarker-in-your-theme-templates
[Look also freemaker guide](http://freemarker.org/docs/index.html)